# Component is not properly rendering in VueJs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I've been learning Vue.js components and I am trying to show data using vue.js and Laravel. But somehow I can't get it rendered properly. Could someone show me what I am doing wrong?

My routes:

[image: laravel app routes]

My gulpfile:

[image: Gulpfile.js]

I'm posting the code. My main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Resource from 'vue-resource';
import App from './components/App.vue';
import HomeView from './components/HomeView.vue';
// Installing some plugins

Vue.use(Router);
Vue.use(Resource);

// Registering filters globally

// Vue.filter();

export var router = new Router({
    history: true
});

router.map({
    '/': {
        name: 'app',
        component: App,
    },
    'test':{
        name: 'test',
        component: HomeView
    }
});

// Redirect 404 pages
router.redirect({
  '*': '/'
});

router.start(App, 'app');
```

My index.blade.view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CRUD WITH VUE JS</title>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,200,300,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="/css/all.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <app>

        </app>
    </div>  


    <script src="/js/main.js">


    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My app.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div id="UserController">
        <form action="#">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
        </form>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>EMAIL</th>
                <th>ADDRESS</th>
                <th>CREATED_AT</th>
                <th>UPDATED_AT</th>
            </thead>
        </table>

        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="user in users">
                <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.address }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.created_at }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.updated_at }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <main>
          <router-view>

          </router-view>
        </main>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import UserServices from '../services/UserServices';

export default{

    props: ['user'],

    data () {
      return {
        users: []
      }
    },

    route: {
        data () {
            return UserServices.getAll()
              .then(({ data }) => ({
          users: data
             }));
          }
    }
}
</script>
```

My UserServices.js which is imported in App.Vue:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {

  getAll () {
    return Vue.http.get('/api/users');
  }
}
```

When viewing in the browser I get this error from my vueDevTools:

```
main.js:5466[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "user.id": TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined (found in component: <router-app>)warn @ main.js:5466Watcher.get @ main.js:7623Watcher @ main.js:7605Directive._bind @ main.js:12792linkAndCapture @ main.js:11375compositeLinkFn @ main.js:11344Vue._compile @ main.js:13058Vue.$mount @ main.js:13893Vue._init @ main.js:6915Vue._init @ main.js:3492VueComponent @ VM2428:2(anonymous function) @ main.js:4299_match @ main.js:4308onChange @ main.js:3904listener @ main.js:2643start @ main.js:2646start @ main.js:40878../components/App.vue @ main.js:14679s @ main.js:1e @ main.js:1(anonymous function) @ main.js:1
main.js:5466[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "user.name": TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined (found in component: <router-app>)warn @ main.js:5466Watcher.get @ main.js:7623Watcher @ main.js:7605Directive._bind @ main.js:12792linkAndCapture @ main.js:11375compositeLinkFn @ main.js:11344Vue._compile @ main.js:13058Vue.$mount @ main.js:13893Vue._init @ main.js:6915Vue._init @ main.js:3492VueComponent @ VM2428:2(anonymous function) @ main.js:4299_match @ main.js:4308onChange @ main.js:3904listener @ main.js:2643start @ main.js:2646start @ main.js:40878../components/App.vue @ main.js:14679s @ main.js:1e @ main.js:1(anonymous function) @ main.js:1
main.js:5466[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "user.email": TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined (found in component: <router-app>)warn @ main.js:5466Watcher.get @ main.js:7623Watcher @ main.js:7605Directive._bind @ main.js:12792linkAndCapture @ main.js:11375compositeLinkFn @ main.js:11344Vue._compile @ main.js:13058Vue.$mount @ main.js:13893Vue._init @ main.js:6915Vue._init @ main.js:3492VueComponent @ VM2428:2(anonymous function) @ main.js:4299_match @ main.js:4308onChange @ main.js:3904listener @ main.js:2643start @ main.js:2646start @ main.js:40878../components/App.vue @ main.js:14679s @ main.js:1e @ main.js:1(anonymous function) @ main.js:1
main.js:5466[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "user.address": TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined (found in component: <router-app>)warn @ main.js:5466Watcher.get @ main.js:7623Watcher @ main.js:7605Directive._bind @ main.js:12792linkAndCapture @ main.js:11375compositeLinkFn @ main.js:11344Vue._compile @ main.js:13058Vue.$mount @ main.js:13893Vue._init @ main.js:6915Vue._init @ main.js:3492VueComponent @ VM2428:2(anonymous function) @ main.js:4299_match @ main.js:4308onChange @ main.js:3904listener @ main.js:2643start @ main.js:2646start @ main.js:40878../components/App.vue @ main.js:14679s @ main.js:1e @ main.js:1(anonymous function) @ main.js:1
main.js:5466[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "user.created_at": TypeError: Cannot read property 'created_at' of undefined (found in component: <router-app>)warn @ main.js:5466Watcher.get @ main.js:7623Watcher @ main.js:7605Directive._bind @ main.js:12792linkAndCapture @ main.js:11375compositeLinkFn @ main.js:11344Vue._compile @ main.js:13058Vue.$mount @ main.js:13893Vue._init @ main.js:6915Vue._init @ main.js:3492VueComponent @ VM2428:2(anonymous function) @ main.js:4299_match @ main.js:4308onChange @ main.js:3904listener @ main.js:2643start @ main.js:2646start @ main.js:40878../components/App.vue @ main.js:14679s @ main.js:1e @ main.js:1(anonymous function) @ main.js:1
main.js:5466 [Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "user.updated_at": TypeError: Cannot read property 'updated_at' of undefined (found in component: <router-app>)
```

Can someone explain please what I am doing wrong? And what needs to be changed for it to be properly rendered?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! In regards to "Due to my account being new, I can't post more pictures, so I'm posting the code", I just wanted to let you know that it's much, MUCH better to post code than to post pictures. Hope someone can help you with your question.

Comment: I sincerely don't understand why would anyone want to post a picture, it's a sincere question.

Comment: On a side-note: I think people are much more likely to respond if you post *only* the **relevant code** and not **ALL** of your code.

Comment: Well I posted all of my code incase someone needs to look into other files in order to answer the question.

Comment: The issue seems to be that the data that your receive from your API does not have the format you need it to be. can you `console.log` the data you get?

Comment: Please delete the images from your code and replace them with formatted text blocks - there is usually no reason to convert text to bitmaps when posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you are getting your variables from an API, and the JS code is being evaulated before finishing the request.

Simply, add a `v-if` condition to your `tbody`

```
    <tbody v-if="users">
        <tr v-for="user in users">
            <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.address }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.created_at }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.updated_at }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Also the methods should be updated

```
methods: {
    getAll () {
         this.$http.get('/api/users').then((response)=>{
               this.users = response.data;
          });
    }
}
```

And the ready function will be:

```
ready(){
     this.getAll();
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same response. v-if is not helping;/

Comment: Did you compile after applying the change?

Comment: Also are you sure the users variable in general is populated correctly?

Comment: I did compile after the change, I am not 100 percent sure that it is populated correctly. If I go to api/users, it does get JSON data. So my assumption is that:  return UserServices.getAll() takes it correctly, and feeds it later after then.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to declare your default data.

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            users: []
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can setup your methods:

```
methods: {
    getAll () {
        return Vue.http.get('/api/users');
    }
}
```

Now we can bind to our `ready ()` function. This will make our API call to get our users. From here, we need to make sure that our components instance of our `users` is fed the new JSON object that comes back from our RESTful endpoint.

```
ready () {
    this.users = this.getAll();
}
```

Now this should work correctly.